# MethodNotAllowedHttpException not found when I paginate in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Hello this is my first question here.

I am using php laravel framework and I am getting this error

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:`

This error comes when I go to second page of the result list.

My controller code.

```
public function find_product(Request $request)
{
    $search = trim($request->product);

    $products = Store_product::(query-for-products-working)
        ->paginate(1);

    return view('fc.product',compact('products','search'));

}
```

My web.php code

```
Route::post('/product', 'FlashCartController@find_product');
```

My view code

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<div class="fc-col">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading fc-col-head"><div class="marquee">{{ $product->product_name }}</div></div>
    <div class="panel-body fc-col-body">
        <img src="{{ image_check('uploads/store/products/',$product->product_image1,'uploads/service/') }}" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height: 100%;" alt="{{ $product->product_name }}" />
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer fc-col-footer">
        <span class="price">Rs.
        {{ 
            price_check($product->product_discount, $product->product_price, $product->sale_id, $product->discount)
        }}/-
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
<div>
    {{ $products->links() }}
</div>
```

and the form

```
<form action="/product" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}  
<div class="input-group container">
  <input type="text" name="product" class="form-control" value="{{$search}}" placeholder="Enter product name" />
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Search" />
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Why my method is not allowed. And if this is not the method to use what should I do?
Can anyone help me with this please? :(

Comment: I would imagine you're not paginating with post?

Comment: How would I do that!? I saw this only method to paginate

Comment: @AneesSaban pagination is always `GET`

Comment: @AliRasheed Exactly, look at his route... I meant it was weird to use POST. ;)

Comment: Yeah! But lets not demoralize the mate. Everyone gets stuck on silly points in starting :D @AneesSaban

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay so your problem as I understand it is that when you paginate to the next page the url becomes empty and no results are shown.

In your view you have this line:

```
 {{ $products->links() }}
```

Which shows that whatever your url is at the moment, just ignore it and add pagination to it.

That means if your url is like `www.abc.com?product=graphics` it will ignore `product` and only add `www.abc.com?page=1,2,...` Of course your page will be blank.

Instead use this:

```
{{ $products->appends(request()->input())->links() }}
```

Now it tells the system to add pagination but append variables to it too. What variables? The variables that are appended on the url already.

Hope it helps

Comment: add {{ $products->appends(request()->input())->links() }} to the view and don't forget to add another get request so it can go through, that's easiest way
Route::get('/product', 'FlashCartController@find_product');